$A\otimes_kB$ is an integral domain when $k$ is algebraically closed, and $A$ and $B$ are finitely generated
I am trying to understand this answer in this math stack exchange post I don't see how it works.
Let $A$ and $B$ be finitely generated $k$ algebras with $k$ algebraically closed, and suppose that $A$ and $B$ are both integral domains. Then $A\otimes_kB$ should also be
an integral domain, and the answer is given by:

By Hilbert's Nullstellensatz, $A \to \prod_{\mathfrak{m}} A/\mathfrak{m}$ is injective, where $\mathfrak{m}$ runs through the maximal ideals of $A$, and in each case we have $A/\mathfrak{m}=k$. The same for $B$. Now if $x,y \in A \otimes_k B$ with $xy=0$ and $y \neq 0$, choose some maximal ideal $\mathfrak{n} \subseteq B$ with $0 \neq y \bmod \mathfrak{n}$. For all $\mathfrak{m} \subseteq A$ it follows that $0 = (x \bmod \mathfrak{m})(y \bmod \mathfrak{n})$ in $A/\mathfrak{m} \otimes_k B/\mathfrak{n}=k \otimes_k k=k$, hence $0 = x \bmod \mathfrak{m}$. This shows $x=0$.

I understand that if $A$ is an integral domain then that map is injective, but what I don't get is the second half of the argument. In a comment the poster states that when they write $ x \bmod \mathfrak{m}$ they are taking the quotient with respect to the ideal generated by $\mathfrak{m}$ in $A\otimes_kB$. I see how this can be canonically identified with $B$, and how the map $A\otimes_kB\longrightarrow A/\mathfrak m\otimes_k A/\mathfrak n$ factors through the projection maps $A\otimes_k B\rightarrow A/\mathfrak m\otimes _k A/\mathfrak n$ and $A\otimes_kB\rightarrow A\otimes_kB/\mathfrak n$, so it makes sense to multiply together. However, $A\otimes_kB$ is a priori not an integral domain so I don't see how we can use injectivity to claim that $x=0$. Moreover, I think it could absolutely be the case that $y\neq 0$ but $y\mod \mathfrak n$ is zero in $A\otimes_kB/\mathfrak n$ or $A/\mathfrak m\otimes_kB/\mathfrak n$ for some $\mathfrak m$ and some $\mathfrak n$.
Are my concerns valid? If not why? If so is there a way to salvage this proof?

We know $A$ and $B$ are flat (since they are free $k$-modules), so the map $A \otimes B \to (\prod_\mathfrak{m} A/\mathfrak m) \otimes B$ is injective.

@Frank This is helpful, but I don't think it completely solves the problem

This allows you to conclude $x = 0$ since the proof shows that $x$ is in the kernel of the map $A \otimes B \to (\prod_\mathfrak{m} A / \mathfrak{m}) \otimes B$. It also tells you that if $y \neq 0$, then there exists some $\mathfrak{n}$ such that the image of $y$ under the map $A \otimes B \to A \otimes (B / \mathfrak{n})$ is nonzero.

@Frank But what if $y$ is in $\mathfrak m$?

@Frank, in particular I see no reason why there could not exist an $\mathfrak m$ such that $[y]\in A\otimes_kB/\mathfrak n$ does not map to $0$ in $A/\mathfrak m\otimes_k B/\mathfrak n$. If this is the case, then we not necessarily have that $[x]\in A/\mathfrak m\otimes_k B$ is zero for all $\mathfrak m$.

Ah, I see the issue now. I'll have to think about it but the proof currently doesn't make a lot of sense. (specifically the step where they conclude $0 = x \bmod \mathfrak{m}$ for all $\mathfrak{m}$)
